# Tabbar makes my view horizontally scrollable

Tags: cordova, dojo, tabbar, scrollable

When I insert a `tabbar` for bottom navigation, I can scroll the whole view a little bit horizontally. I tried the `scrollDir` command for the `scrollableview` but that doesn't work. I don't want the view to be horizontally scrollable.

Comment: Have you tried setting the DOM node's `overflow-x` style to `overflow-x: hidden`?

Comment: Great idea, that fixed it. Thank you very much! The only bad thing is that the tabbar is now dissapeared when i open the the index.html on the PCs Browser but its still there on iphone

Comment: It should not be necessary to set overflow-x. You could experience other issue, for example if you want to put a button on the right of the title bar, it would be clipped. Do you reproduce using an existing sample such as http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.8.3/dojo-release-1.8.3/dojox/mobile/tests/test_TabBar-syncWithViews.html ?

Comment: it is reproduceable with this example when i copy it into my project and replace my tabbar